# Apache2 configuration. Different PHP versions

Tags: server, apache2, php

I have a big problem with MyBB. I uploaded the files fine, gave rights 777.

`000-default.conf` entry from apache2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.1.19
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/web/

    <Directory /var/www/web>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/web_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/web_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.1.19
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mybb/

    <Directory /var/www/mybb>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mybb_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mybb_access.log combined

    Alias /mybb /var/www/mybb

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.1.19
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
    
    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/phpmyadmin_access.log combined

    Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
</VirtualHost>
```

After typing `192.168.1.19/mybb` does not work, same if I type `192.168.1.19/mybb/install` or `192.168.1.19/install`

MyBB must be using version 8.1. How to fix this? I have no strength left. ChatGPT can't help, I don't know anything about it. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Apache version is 2.4.56, mariadb version is 10.11.2, php version is 8.1.17 (All packages from the stable release)

`/var/ww/web` and phpmyadmin must use php 8.2. The site and phpmyadmin work, but mybb does not.

Comment: I would *strongly* suggest replacing `777` with `755` unless you want your websites to be “hacked” by a drive-by script kiddie. Only the web server should be permitted to write files on the server 

Comment: I know, but it was for testing. I changed it to 755, thanks ! :)

Comment: What is inside `/var/www/mybb/`? Could you paste the output of `ls /var/www/mybb/`?

Comment: You have three `VirtualHost` configurations with the same `ServerName`. Only the first configuration that matches will be used. The other VirtualHosts will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You've configured several vhosts with the same ServerName 192.168.1.19 on the same port (80). Since the last vhos takes precedence over the others phpmyadmin will work. You can make it work by using different ports for each site. For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:8082>
...
<VirtualHost *:8081>
...
<VirtualHost *:8080>
...
```

Comment: Changed to: https://pastebin.com/5V1eMWfV And mybb still doesn't work. There is an error somewhere in this file, I just don't know where :( After editing the file, I ran the command sudo systemctl restart apache2

Comment: Please show the error you get. Don’t forget to add the Listen instruction for each port